# Django form action "." reloads same page with missing slug

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm following a basic tutorial which adds commenting to a blog post detail page. I am navigating to the detail page with the absolute_url method and it works perfectly fine.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
return reverse('blog:post_detail',
               args=[self.publish.year,
                     self.publish.month,
                     self.publish.day,
                     self.slug])
```

Here is a sample url created by the get_absolute_url

```
http://localhost:8000/blog/2019/5/2/second-post
```

However, when I submit the form within the detail page with the action=".", it only returns the date parameters and missing the slug part.

```
<form action="." method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ comment_form.as_p }}
  <p><input type="submit" value="Add comment"></p>
</form>
```

Here is the returned url

```
http://localhost:8000/blog/2019/5/2/
```

adding `action="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"` seems to solve the problem but the book I am following [`Django 2 By Example`](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/django-2-example) tells it should just work fine with action="."

I'm new to Django and Development so thank you for your help and understanding if the question is noob in any way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show your URL patterns, but they should all end with `/`. So the original URL of `http://localhost:8000/blog/2019/5/2/second-post` should be `http://localhost:8000/blog/2019/5/2/second-post/`. For example, the pattern might be:

```
path('blog/<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:slug>/', views.blog, 'blog'),
```

which ends with a slash and so the generated path will also end with a slash. Then posting to "." will work properly.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes that was the case. It was `/<slug:slug>` not `/<slug:slug>/` I changed my path and appended a `/` Now it works perfectly. Thank you again :)